# Byte Array to Bitmap Image

Tags: c#, arrays, bitmap, byte

I made this code to receive an image and convert it to bitmap image but it doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
public void ReceiveImage()
{
    NetworkStream stream = new NetworkStream(socket);
    byte[] data = new byte[4];
    stream.read(data,0,data.length,0)
    int size = BitConverter.ToInt32(data,0);
    data = new byte[size];
    stream.read(data,0,data.length)
    MemoryStream imagestream = new MemoryStream(data);
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(imagestream);
    picturebox1.Image = bmp;
}
```

It gets to:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(imagestream);
```

And gives me this error:

> Parameter is not valid

Comment: @Tarek...is this C# Code?  When I copy it into Visual Studio, it has some typos.

Comment: yes its C# , but you have to type                
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;

Comment: And also using System.Drawing.Imaging;

Comment: Maybe you are not being sent valid image data?

Comment: Parameter is not valid is given when the parameter is not a valid image. I assume there is some issue with the way you are reading the file

Answer (score 9):

This is an alternative method

```
int w= 100;
int h = 200;
int ch = 3; //number of channels (ie. assuming 24 bit RGB in this case)

byte[] imageData    = new byte[w*h*ch]; //you image data here
Bitmap bitmap       = new Bitmap(w,h,PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
BitmapData bmData   = bitmap.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bitmap.PixelFormat);
IntPtr pNative      = bmData.Scan0;
Marshal.Copy(imageData,0,pNative,w*h*ch);
bitmap.UnlockBits(bmData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably not receiving enough bytes in `stream.read(data,0,data.length)` since `Read` does not ensure that it will read `data.length` bytes. you have to check its return value and continue to read till `data.Length` bytes are read.

See : [Stream.Read Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read.aspx)'s return value

```
int read = 0;
while (read != data.Length)
{
    read += stream.Read(data, read, data.Length - read);
}
```

PS: I am assuming `length`s and `read`s are typos.

Comment: this error happened
'Unable to read data from the transport connection. An operation on a socket could be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full.'

Comment: Check the `size`. It can be in [network byte order](http://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-big-and-little-endian-byte-order/). You can try `IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(BitConverter.ToInt32(data,0))`

Comment: not working, comes to 'data = new byte[size];'
then gives me this error
'Arithmetic Operation Resulted in an overflow'

Comment: @TarekAdel What do you expect me to do with so little info shown in your question? OK, I found an explicit bug in your code but I am not a magician. What kind of server/client do you have on the other side of your connection? in which protocol does it send the image?

Comment: i cant send you the code cuz its more than 800 Chars , how can i send it to you?, if by Facebook, this is my email tarek55544@live.com

Comment: @TarekAdel SO doesn't work that way. If you want an answer post the code here (or somewhere else and give a link) But please think: "*Is this info enough to answer my question*"

Comment: i cant the code is more than 800 chars and i cant post except only 600 Chars

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a table and want to receive the picture from database.

```
int cout = ds.Tables["TableName"].Rows.Count;
                if (cout > 0)
                {
                    if (ds.Tables["TableName"].Rows[cout - 1]["Image"] != DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        var data = (byte[])(ds.Tables["TableName"].Rows[cout - 1]["Image"]);
                        var stream = new MemoryStream(data);
                        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pictureBox1.Image = null;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Your assumption is probably wrong. see the code `NetworkStream`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
int size = BitConverter.ToInt32(data.Reverse().ToArray(),0);
```

Comment: `Try this` is just a comment. `Try this. This should work because...` is an answer.