# Adding an image from memory stream to Excel document

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I have an image in a memory stream and I want to write this to an MS Excel document, the PIA only exposes the AddPicture method which takes a file path.

Is there away to add a picture without having to write the image to disc?

MSDN

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.shapes.addpicture(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: can you add the code you have please? the few lines which add data to memorystream (picture format?) variable and the AddPicture or range/cell where you want the picture to be

Comment: I don't really have any code for this, I'm looking to add this to an existing excel document generation process.

Comment: and you have a MemoryStream(ByteArrayImage), right?

Comment: This still doesn't have a complete answer. The current answer doesn't replace the string to a filename.

Answer (score 6):

Well, a bit of blind flying but assuming a thing or two about your code (e.g. the source of your stream, data type, etc) this could be a solution:
First, you need to create  bitmap image data from the stream (which I assume is a byte stream, also assuming that the stream describes a bitmap image). There's a solution already for that here on Stack Overflow: [Byte Array to Bitmap Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11730373/byte-array-to-bitmap-image) 
I copy-paste the code from the solution:

```
int w= 100;
int h = 200;
int ch = 3; //number of channels (ie. assuming 24 bit RGB in this case)

byte[] imageData    = new byte[whch]; //you image data here
Bitmap bitmap       = new Bitmap(w,h,PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
BitmapData bmData   = bitmap.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bitmap.PixelFormat);
IntPtr pNative      = bmData.Scan0;
Marshal.Copy(imageData,0,pNative,whch);
bitmap.UnlockBits(bmData);
```

Also assuming you have an object for your workbook and the worksheet you are about to work with, something like this:

```
xlBook = (Excel.Workbook)objExcel.Workbooks.Add("");
xlSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlBook.Worksheets1;
xlSheet.Activate();
```

Now that you have a Bitmap-type variable, and a worksheet, all you need is to paste the image to the sheet:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetDataObject(bitmap, false);
xlsRange = xlSheet.get_Range((Excel.Range)xlSheet.Cells[5, 15], (Excel.Range)xlSheet.Cells[5, 15]);
xlSheet.Paste(xlsRange, bitmap);
```

So the key is this guy here (instead of using "AddPicture"): [Worksheet.Paste Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.paste%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Mark thanks for such a complete answer, will up vote when implemented

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work for me - the code is executing on a background (task pool) thread and therefore it's not an STA thread, Clipboard requires this.

Comment: tricky, you are. new rule. how about the evergreen "[threadobjvar].SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);" ?

Comment: the thread state has already been set, because it's a background thread, and attempting to set it again barfs

Comment: for the above solution you need to create a new thread then and start -inside the current/running one-

Comment: we don't create threads manually and importantly don't want to, but thanks for the idea

Comment: This is still not a complete answer. It was supposed to replace a string pointing to a file name.