# C# Interop add image from URL

Tags: c#, interop

Is there any way to insert a image to the `Excel Worksheet` by grabbing it from a URL address?

The only method I've found is to add the image by specifying the file path...

```
InlineShape AddPicture(
    string FileName,
    ref Object LinkToFile,
    ref Object SaveWithDocument,
    ref Object Range
)
```

Comment: you could save it to a temporary path, since excel includes images into the xlsx file so you don't need to have it permanently in the same place

Comment: This link describes if you convert your image to stream and then paste it to excel sheet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317455/adding-an-image-from-memory-stream-to-excel-document

Comment: I'll go trying to save it to a temporary path. It seems that there is no way to insert image from a URL...