# Convert C++ data to float array in c#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, interop

There is one C++ function as below which returns me data in unsigned char**

```
MyCPPFunc(unsigned char** ppData, int &nSize)
```

I want to convert it to float array in C#. Problem is that internal representation of data returned by CPP could be char\ushort\uint\RGB etc. If I would use as below,

```
var srcArray = new byte[nSize];
Marshal.Copy(pCPPData, srcArray, 0, nSize/4);
outDataArray = Array.ConvertAll<byte, float>(srcArray, Convert.ToSingle);
```

It would convert every four consecutive bytes to float, while data in memory could be of different data type length (could be ushort, uchar, RGB etc.)

How to do this in a best performing manner, considering c++ library do support lots of data types and returns data in memory of that type.(although that is represented by uchar**)

I need something of this sort as below. where dataTypeLen can be 1 for char, 2 for short and so on.

```
Array.Convert(pCPPData, 0, pFloatArray, dataTypeLen, floatArrLen);
```

Unsafe code will also suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I dont recall any such intelligent Convert'er in the Marshaller. Except for some bold exceptions like String or StringBuilder or Pointers/Handles itself, the Marshaller does not convert datatypes. It gets some bytes and interpretes them as the format(datatype) you requested and returns the format(datatype) you requested. If you ask it to read SHORT then it will decode as SHORT and return a SHORT. It is "not intelligent enough" to know how to convert CHAR into FLOAT. **It's just not the job of Marshaller.** And, also, not the job of any standard Converter. They can convert/cast simple types one to each other (like double to decimal), but they will not be able to understand more complex structures like "RGB", or, worse, some RGB* with padding to 32bits or BMP with padding at end of the row!

Unless you take some intelligent converter that **understands** the **exact** format you have at input, you have to do it manually. You first need to precisely know what type of data it is (uchar, ushort, RGB, etc) and then receive (i.e. marshal) the array in that precise format (uchar[], ushort[], ..) and only then you will be able to convert the elements to floats on the C# side. If you try reading the bytes "just like that", you might run into endianess problems. Of course, you might not care, depending on your needs.

So, for example: if you know that the pCPPData points to uchar array, then unmarshal it as uchar[]; if you know that the pCPPData points to ushort array, then unmarshal it as ushort[]; rgb? unmarshal it as bytes[] or as ints[], depending on the bitdepth of a single color. Then, take the resulting array, loop over it and convert to a new array of floats. (or, just LINQize with `.Cast<float>().ToArray()` and forget).

However, looking a bit out of the box, you seem to with with some kind of bitmaps. uchar-8bit grayscale, ushort-16bit grayscale, RGB-blah, I guess.. So why dont you try using some **Bitmap** processors? I dont precisely recall now, but there are functions and classes in .Net that handle/wrap raw byte arrays as `Image`/`Bitmap` objects.

For example, see ie. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16300450/717732 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/9560495/717732 - in the latter note the comments, they suggest that you could **even** set the `scan0` to an unmanaged pointer, so you might completely escape the need of marshalling/copying anything. You might get a Bitmap object what just reads directly from the pointer you got from C++ library - and it would read in the format as specified by the `ImageFormat` specifier you provided. I have not ever tried this, so I say just "*might*".

But, of course, that would not give you `float[]` but `Bitmap` with `pixels`. If you really need floats, then you'll have to convert it "manually": branch over format, then read them out as the format specifies, then store them in format you want.